# Android HTTP User Agent

Tags: android, http, connection

How do I get the real device in http_user_agent?
When I use a WebView, I can get the real value like this:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0(Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-gb; LG-P500 Build/FRF91) 
AppleWebKit/533.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

But when I use an Apache connection, the result is different:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE(java 1.4).
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you don't want to call `setHeader()` for every request you create you can set the http client parameter `CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT`. After doing this HTTP client will automatically add this header parameter to each request.

Something like:

```
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Custom user agent");
```

when you create your `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 75):

To complete the accepted answer, if you want the default user agent use **System.getProperty("http.agent")**

```
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,
                                System.getProperty("http.agent"));
```

Comment: this one is the better answer than the answers above! thanks!

Comment: The other answers don't answer the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If you want to set your own user agent header then you have to use the `setHeader` method.

In case of a HTTP Post request you just set it like this.

```
private String url = "http://myfancyurl.com/";
private String ua = "My Custom UA Header String";

private HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader("User-Agent", ua);
```

This was just a short explanation how to set a custom user agent string. Your code might look different. The important part is the `setHeader` method.

Comment: In this case, i didn't want to set my own user agent. I want it to be automatic like i get in WebView. Is there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Actually you shouldn't use other http clients User Agents, as some server serve different content depending on the user agent (i.e. optimized content for that browser)

Comment: Well if you have a special case where you have a service depending on a custom user agent string then there is no way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can read useragent using webview:

```
new WebView(this).getSettings().getUserAgentString();
```

Or using system property:

```
System.getProperty("http.agent")
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610164/3317927