# Set default User Agent in Android?

Tags: android, user-agent

Could someone tell me where "default android user agent string" is defined in?

Comment: See [this][1] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904467/android-http-user-agent

Comment: Thanks for your information, but i want to know where is the initial user agent string defined in?
Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

**WebView** is equipped with user agent string. You can get or set it for your WebViews manually too.

```
/* for example */

//get
String ua = webview.getSettings().getUserAgentString();

//set
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("your custom user agent string");
```

Comment: Thank you for your information, but i want to know that where is the default value of user-agent string, or where does the method getUserAgentString() get this value from?

Comment: sorry, no idea... perhaps you can make a search on system files if your phone is rooted

Answer (score 0):

Trying something if you want your Webview to report a non-default user agent. The user agent can vary from application to application.

```
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");
```

Comment: Yes, we could use setUserAgentString() set that value.
But my point is where is the default value of user agent string  defined in?
As the information from my searching, the initial value of user agent string is web_user_agent_target_content, but i can not find where did it declare in android source code?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Are you building a custom rom or something?

Answer (score 0):

Goto `chrome://version` and it should show the default user agent.

[image]