# Same Login Authentication for browser and android app using Servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets, authentication

Hi I am building a Login Module for android native app.There is a login module for the website.

I want to use same servlet to validate Userid and password, both for browser and android app.

I want to

1) Redirect user to a new jsp page if the user logs in thru browser
2) I want to send a success/error response code to android app if he requests thru the app.

i am good with redirecting user to a new jsp. but how to check if user logs in thru android app.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write you app using a given [httpuser.agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904467/android-http-user-agent) on android and filter it out in your servlet ?

Comment: Thanks! You mean setting custom user-agent?